# Украинские фамилии

Tags: ономастика, склонение-фамилий, фамилии

Украинские фамилии оканчивающиеся на *-ко* (Матвиенко) и *-ок* (Цапок) и мужского и женского родов склоняются?
Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2):

Украинская фамилия *Матвиенко* в русском языке не склоняется (в разговорной речи склонение допустимо).
Мужская фамилия *Цапок* склоняется, женская – нет.

> **3.** Сразу  опишем несколько групп несклоняемых фамилий. В современном русском литературном языке **не склоняются** русские фамилии, **оканчивающиеся на -ых, -их** (типа *Черных, Долгих*), а также все фамилии, оканчивающиеся на гласные **е, и, о, у, ы, э, ю.**
>
> Примеры: *тетради Ирины Черных, Лидии Мейе, Романа Грымау; диплом  выдан Виктору Долгих, Андрею Гретри, Николаю Штаненко, Майе Ли; встреча с Николаем Кручёных и Александром Минадзе.*
>
> Примечание. В разговорной речи и в языке художественной литературы, отражающем устную речь, считается допустимым склонение мужских фамилий на *-ых, -их* (*в сценарии Черныха, встреча с Рыжихом*), а также склонение фамилий украинского происхождения на *-ко, -енко* по склонению существительных женского рода на *-а: пойти к Семашке, в гостях у Устименки.* Отметим, что украинские фамилии такого типа последовательно склонялись в художественной литературе XIX века (*у Шевченки; исповедь Наливайки; стихотворение, посвященное Родзянке*).
>
> **4.** Если фамилия оканчивается на согласный (кроме фамилий на *-ых, -их,* о которых говорилось выше), то здесь – и только здесь! – имеет значение пол носителя фамилии. **Все мужские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на согласный, склоняются – это закон русской грамматики.** Все женские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на согласный, не склоняются. При этом языковое происхождение фамилии не имеет значения. Склоняются в том числе и мужские фамилии, совпадающие с нарицательными существительными.
>
> Примеры: *тетрадь Михаила Бока, дипломы выданы Александру Кругу и Константину Королю, встреча с Игорем Шипелевичем, в гостях у Андрея Мартынюка, дочь Ильи Скалозуба, работа Исаака Акопяна; тетрадь Анны Бок, дипломы выданы Наталье Круг и Лидии Король, встреча с Юлией Шипелевич, в гостях у Екатерины Мартынюк, дочь Светланы Скалозуб, работа Марины Акопян.*

Источник: [Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_8_familii).